# Add fee for COD, unless local pickup is chosen on WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, fee

I currently have active code in WooCommerce and it works fine. The code allows me to apply an extra cost when the customer chooses the "COD' pyament method, + € 1.7

What I would like to understand is this:

Is it possible to disable the extra cost when the customer chooses to collect the goods from our warehouse?

Here is the code:

```php
// Add a custom fee based o cart subtotal
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_handling_fee', 10, 1 );
function custom_handling_fee ( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    if ( 'cod' === WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method') ) {
        $fee = 1.7;
        $cart->add_fee( 'Extra per pagamento alla consegna', $fee, true );
    }
}
// jQuery - Update checkout on methode payment change
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jqscript' );
function custom_checkout_jqscript() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `cod` is a payment method, `local_pickup` is a shipping method.

- `WC()->session->get( 'chosen_payment_method' );`
- `WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );`

So to come to an answer to your question, you will have to use a combination of the 2.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    
    // Chosen payment method
    $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_payment_method' );
    
    // Chosen shipping method
    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping_method = substr( $chosen_shipping_methods[0], 0, strpos( $chosen_shipping_methods[0], ':' ) );

    // Compare payment method & shipping method
    if ( $chosen_payment_method == 'cod' && $chosen_shipping_method != 'local_pickup' ) {
        // Fee
        $fee = 1.7;
        
        // Add fee
        $cart->add_fee( __( 'Extra per pagamento alla consegna', 'woocommerce'), $fee, true );   
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 10, 1 );

// jQuery - Update checkout on method payment change
function custom_checkout_jqscript() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
            $( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jqscript' );
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank you! I hope this post can help other people too.